# Word to describe somebody who is kind-hearted, but also can't be bullied

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe somebody who is generous, loving, and warm, but also capable of harsh retaliation if somebody crosses them. In other words, a person with a heart of gold who can "take care of him/herself".

Answer (score 1):

[free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/an+iron+fist+in+a+velvet+glove)

the closest phrase I can think of would be;

"an iron fist in a velvet glove"

it's not ideal and would usually be used to describe someone who would take the soft approach first and then the harder line.

Answer (score 0):

Moral. Those are universal moral tenets.

http://personal.tcu.edu/pwitt/universal%20values.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could say, "a gentle giant".

Comment: Can you explain what the phrase means, give examples of how it has been used, and tell why it makes a good answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

**Paladin** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/paladin?s=t))

```
Any determined advocate or defender of a noble cause.
```

**Knightly** ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/knightly?s=t))

```
Characteristic of a knight; noble, courageous, and generous.
```

Neither of these words, by themselves, really carries the suggestion of "loving and warm" (I'm wracking my brain looking for such a word but no luck so far) but that easily comes across in the context or can be added by some other modifier. A tender knight, a loving paladin. He was her paladin.

A fierce protector.

An uncompromising guardian.